# Is it possible to use a lambda function inside of a vector's constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda, initialization

Is there a way to initialize all values of some container using a lambda function like one would do using `std::for_each`?  I need a 3-dimensional `std::vector` of random `int`s, and it would be nice if I could do this within the constructor without having to do another `std::for_each` loop.

I have tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
#include <iostream>     /* std::cout */
#include <vector>       /* std::vector */
#include <algorithm>    /* std::for_each */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */



int main(){

    srand(time(nullptr));

    /* only initializes first element, count[0][0][0] */
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> count{100, 
        std::vector<std::vector<int>>{100, 
            std::vector<int>{100, 
            [](){
              return = rand() % 100; 
            }()
          }
       }
    };

    int temp = 0;

   /* here is how I access all elements using std::for_each and lambdas */
   std::for_each(std::begin(count), std::end(count), 
   [&temp](std::vector<std::vector<int>> i){
        std::for_each(std::begin(i), std::end(i), [&temp](std::vector<int> j){
            std::for_each(std::begin(j), std::end(j), [&temp](int k) {
                if(k > temp){
                    temp = k;
                }
            });
        });
    });

}
```

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of the innermost vectors will *all* be initialized from the result of invoking your lambda, i.e. `rand() % 100`. They will all be initialized to the same value, and there is no way to get the lambda invoked every time an element (in your case, an `int`) needs to be initialized.

If you really, really want that to happen transparently, you could just create a type of your own that behaves exactly like an `int`, but gets default-initialized the way you want:

```
struct RandomInitInt
{
    RandomInitInt() { i = rand() % 100; }
    RandomInitInt(int i) : i(i) { }
    operator int () { return i; }
    int i;
};
```

You would then use it this way:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<RandomInitInt>>> count(100,
    std::vector<std::vector<RandomInitInt>>(100,
        std::vector<RandomInitInt>(100)
      )
   );
```

And replace every occurrence of `vector<int>` with `vector<RandomInitInt>`.

But again, consider this only if you're desperate about eliminating that loop. Personally, I think the presence of the loop is clearer about the way the vector is initialized - meaning it communicates your intent better.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  Guess I'll just initialize it in a loop.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Feels like std::generate/std::generate_n is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Since calling a lambda in the `vector`'s constructor initializes all the values to the same number (as mentioned in the previous answer), I deem the following the best way to initialize a 3D `vector` of `int`s to `rand() % 100`:

```
srand(time(nullptr));
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> count{100, std::vector<std::vector<int>>{100, std::vector<int>{100, 0}}};

for(auto& i : count){
    for(auto& j : i){
        for(auto& k : j){
            k = rand() % 100;
        }
    }
}
```